# Unexpected Parameter Issue in Laravel Route Resource

Tags: php, laravel-10

I am defining a group of routes using `Route::resource` in a Laravel project. However, when I use the `php artisan route:list` command, I observe an unexpected parameter structure in the URLs created for the resources. Specifically, instead of having a variable name inside curly braces in the pattern like `admin/mail/{variable}`, I see `{}` as an empty parameter.

### Routes File Example(web.php):

```
Route::prefix('admin/mail')->name('admin.mail.')
  ->group(function () {
    Route::resource('/', MailController::class);
    Route::resource('/future', MailController::class);
    Route::resource('/draft', DraftMailController::class);
 });
```

### Output Screenshot(php artisan route:list):

[image: Route List Output]

### Problem Details:

- In the output of the `php artisan route:list` command, I can see that the unexpected parameter name is `{}`.
- Laravel version: 10

### Troubleshooting Steps:

1. I have checked the route definitions in the `routes/web.php` file and ensured they are configured correctly.
2. I cleared the Laravel cache using the `php artisan route:clear` command.
3. I reloaded classes and files using the `composer dump-autoload` command.
4. I verified the naming and namespace of the controller classes.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTUsl.png

Comment: I tried this  Route::resource('/', MailController::class)->parameters(['mail']); doesnt work

Comment: try comment `Route::resource('/', MailController::class);`, do those `admin/mail/{}` gone?

Comment: no return 404 error

Comment: on the `route:list`, is it gone? i think it would best to have `Route::resource('/', MailController::class);` as `Route::resource('/admin/mail', MailController::class);` and declared **before** the route prefix - dont forget to give a different name for it. i think the `/` inside prefix causes the problem, it confuses laravel.

Comment: Okey but, when i use like this;

Route::prefix('mail')->name('mail.')->group(function(){
  
  Route::get('/create', [MailController::class,"create"])->name('create');
  Route::post('/', [MailController::class,"store"])->name('store');
  Route::get('/{mail}', [MailController::class,"show"])->name('show');
  

  //Route::resource('/', MailController::class);

  Route::resource('/future', MailController::class);
  Route::resource('draft', DraftMailController::class);
 });

this correctly work

Comment: If you're defining nested resource routes within the same endpoint, Laravel might use empty parameters to avoid conflicts. Restructure your routes to avoid nesting resources with the same controller at the same endpoint. Consider using different prefixes or moving nested resources to separate controllers.

Comment: If /future is alias to /, you could just do Route::redirect('/future', '/') maybe

Comment: I think this might be a bug, i reported this